# Solaris 10 i386 vmstat giving more free than swap

Tags: unix, memory, solaris, admin

How come when running vmstat on Solaris 10 i386 I got more free space than swap space? Isn't free a proportion of swap which is available?

```
$ vmstat
 kthr      memory            page            disk          faults      cpu
 r b w   swap  free  re  mf pi po fr de sr s0 s1 -- --   in   sy   cs us sy id
 1 0 0 7727088 17137388 37 303 1 0 0  0  0 -0  4  0  0 7247 7414 8122  4  1 95
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Free RAM represent the part of RAM that is immediately available to use while free swap represent part of virtual memory which is neither allocated or reserved. Reserved memory doesn't physically use any storage (RAM or disk).

Have a look at `swap -s` output for details.